# ¿Como leer una matriz de caracteres de un .txt y almacenarlo en un array bidimensional String? (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, archivo, matrices, split

Tengo un archivo `.txt` el cual contiene una matriz de caracteres de 6x5 separadas solo por comas.

[image: Estructura del archivo]

Por lo que me gustaría se guardara en un arreglo bidimensional de tipo String y que quedara de la siguiente forma:

[image: Forma esperada]

De código solo he conseguido leer el archivo mas no tengo idea de como codificar la forma en que me gustaría guardar el texto.

```
 public static void leerArchivo(String ruta) {

    String dato;

    try {
        File archivo = new File(ruta);
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(archivo);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            dato = myReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(dato);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe");
    }
}
```

He estado investigando y con la funcion `split` se puede separar los caracteres de las comas, mas sin embargo no tengo idea de como implementarlo en mi codigo, espero y alguien pudiera ayudarme, de antemano gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma, como comentas separas inicialmente los caracteres separados por coma en un array usando `split()` , cada renglon lo almacenarias en un array dimensionado de esta forma:

```
   String[][] myMatrix = new String[6][5];
```

Este serìa el còdigo:

```
   String dato;
   String[][] myMatrix = new String[6][5];

    try {
        File archivo = new File(ruta);
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(archivo);
        int row = 0;
        String[] info;
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            dato = myReader.nextLine();
            info = dato.split(",");
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                myMatrix[row][i] = info[i];
            }
            row++;               
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         System.out.println("El archivo no existe");
    }
```

El valor del array `myMatrix` contendrà los valores de la matriz.

De esta forma podras imprimir el array para comprobar que los valores fueron almacenados.

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myMatrix));
```

teniendo como salida:

```
[[a, s, d, f, a], [a, d, f, s, d], [a, f, d, f, d], [d, f, s, a, f], [s, f, d, a, f], [a, f, d, s, f]]
```

---

Otra forma para realizar la impresión de los datos en la matriz sería:

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){ 
      for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){ 
          System.out.print(myMatrix[j][k]+" "); 
      } 
      System.out.println(""); 
  }
```

para obtener como salida :

```
a s d f a 
a d f s d 
a f d f d 
a f s a f 
s f d a f 
a f d s f
```

Comment: Solo una duda, para mostrar la matriz final habria una forma que no fuera usando arrayList? es que no nos dejan usarlo en nuestras tareas, de hecho intente hacer con las siguientes lineas de codigo pero me tira error, pero con la linea del sout que tu pones si me lo imprime, las lineas de codigo que he intentado usar son

for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){
            for (int k = 0; k < myArray.length; k++){
                System.out.print(myArray[j][k]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

Comment: No se ven bien las lineas de codigo que puse, pero practicamente son los dos tipicos ciclos for aniadados que se usan para mostrar una matriz

Comment: @EduardoHerrera usa la variable myMatrix no myArray, y no uses .length usa el valor de la cantidad de filas y columnas , revisa lo que agregue en mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Excelente, gracias